# Always have reliable orientation

Tags: android, view, orientation

Basically my goal is to set some custom `View` size exactly to **1/3** of the screen for `portrait` orientation and **1/6** for `landscape`

The first thought that came to my mind is to simply calculate some `mSize` variable and set it to the `View` in `OnMeasure` like this:

```
  mSize = (AContext.getScreenSize().x / (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT  ? 3 : 6)

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(mSize|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, mSize|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
  }
```

And it's working just fine, till i rotate the screen. The thing is that  when screen is rotating `View` initialization and sizing are called **before** the `orientation` value will actually change, so the result is that it goes **one third to `landscape`** also, if it was opened with `portrait` orientation firstly, and other way around.

I'm aware that i can do something like :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

In `AndroidManifest` for my `Activity` and override `onConfigurationChanged` to handle the rotation and change `mSize` value there, but, **it disables auto choosing between `portrait` and `landscape` layouts**(from `.xml` files on `inflating`). So i'm ending up with the same `xml` file for both orientations.

Is there a way to keep `orientation` value from `context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` consistent?

Or i need to do some workaround with `onConfigurationChange` to enable layout choosing?(*i don't want to do it maually in code thou*)

Or is there a better way to achieve my goal, and i'm just doing it wrong from the start?

Please help me.

Comment: @MaximG, thanks for the reply, but going throw introduction i can't quite see how it can help me. For some clerifications : i need view to be 1/3 and 1/6 of any screen depens on orientation. Is it possible to do here? Because what i see in screens is just dp value for size

Comment: Have you tried with a treeviewobserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I would say to not use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` on this situation. It makes no sense such a thing on a custom view.

Secondly I believe the main mistake is the way you're capturing the 3, or 6 values. As you can achieve it much simpler using XML.

```
res/values/integers.xml
   <integer name="view_fraction">3</integer>
res/values-land/integers.xml
   <integer name="view_fraction">6</integer>
```

Then during your view **constructor** you simply call:

```
int val = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.view_fraction)
```

Furthermore, I will offer some other suggested improve on your view size calculation by suggesting you to simply use code that Google provides us, instead of trying to re-code it. Using the classes from `android.support.percent`

If your custom view extends from `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` I would suggest you to instead extend from their percent counterpart [`PercentFrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) and [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

If the custom view does not extends from one of those, you can use their helper [`PercentLayoutHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentLayoutHelper.html) following the guide on their page.

That way you can easily dinamically assing percentage of view size on your XML layout

Comment: About percentage: it's a bit tricky one, you see, this view of mine is a item of RecyclerView, further more, i can put my RecyclerView into PercentageLayout and set size to it, but it's gonna be height of the view only, and width should be the same, this is an ImageView which should resize loaded image depending on screen orientation in right moment, so for the width i would need to override onMeaseure and provide my code anyway, i hope you understand, i will try suggestion with resources now, and will provide info on how it worked, thanks for the reply